# apache cxf maven plugin wsdl wildcard configurations

Tags: maven, path, wsdl, cxf, relative-path

In a maven project structure, I have several wsdls/schemas organised inside separate folders under resources folder. I have to configure apache cxf maven plugin in pom.xml to generate classes from all the wsdls. How can i configure a relative path with wildcard for this? I used the following but was not successful.

```
<wsdlOption>                                       
 <wsdl>${basedir}/src/main/resources/wsdl/**/*.wsdl</wsdl>
</wsdlOption>
```

Please let me know how i can configure such a relative path.

Answer (score 0):

From [CXF doc](http://cxf.apache.org/docs/maven-cxf-codegen-plugin-wsdl-to-java.html#Mavencxf-codegen-plugin%28WSDLtoJava%29-Example5%3aUsingwsdlRootwithincludes/excludespatterns), you should be able to do it like this:

```
<configuration>
    <sourceRoot>${project.build.directory}/generated/cxf</sourceRoot>
    <wsdlRoot>${project.basedir}/src/main/resources/wsdl</wsdlRoot>
    <includes>
        <include>*.wsdl</include>
    </includes>
</configuration>
```